# useQuery and useState

Tags: reactjs, dictionary, state

I am trying to use `setState` to set data from a `useQuery` with the Apollo Client using the `OnCompleted` function, however it doesn't seem to set the data and I am struggling to find out why.

Also, will my table mapping update accordingly once the `setState` is set?

The `console.log` in the `handleSubmit` function is always empty, and nothing maps. But if I do `data.horses` console log it is there.

Here is my code:

```
import { useQuery, gql } from "@apollo/client";
import { useState } from "react";

const DataTable = () => {
const GET_HORSES = gql`
query{
    horses{
        horseCode
        horseName
        foalingYear
        gender
        trainer{
            trainerCode
        }
    }
}`; 

const [horses, setHorses] = useState([]);
const { data, loading, error} = useQuery(GET_HORSES, {
    OnCompleted: (data) => setHorses(data.horses)
});

if (loading) { return "Loading..." };
if (error) { return "Error loading data!"};
if (!data) { return "No data available!"};

const handleSubmit = () => {
    var ddSearch = document.getElementById("ddSearch");
    var ddSearchVal = ddSearch.value;

    if(ddSearchVal === "HorseCode") {

    }
    
    console.log(horses);
}

return (
    <div className="flex-column">
        <div className="Data-search">
            <strong>Searching</strong>
            <br/>
            <select id="ddSearch" >
                <option value="HorseCode">Horse Code</option>
                <option value="TrainerCode">Trainer Code</option>
                <option value="HorseName">Horse Name</option>
            </select>
            <br/>
            <input type="txtSearch" id="search" style={{width: 94}}/>
            <br/><br/>
            <strong>Foaling Year</strong>
            <br />
            From:<br/>
            <input type="number" id="foalingYearMin" min="2000" max="2010" style={{width: 94}} /><br/>
            To:<br/>
            <input type="number" id="foalingYearMax" min="2000" max="2010" style={{width: 94}} />
            <br/><br/>
            <strong>Gender:</strong><br/>
            <select id="ddGender" style={{width: 94}}>
                <option value="g">g</option>
                <option value="f">f</option>
                <option value="c">c</option>
            </select>
            <br/><br/>
            <button type="button" style={{width: 94}} onClick={() => handleSubmit()}>Search</button>
            <br/>
            <button type="button" style={{width: 94}}>Reset</button>
        </div>
        <table className="Data-table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Horse Code</th>
                    <th>Horse Name</th>
                    <th>Foaling Year</th>
                    <th>Gender</th>
                    <th>Trainer Code</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                {horses.map((horse) => (
                    <tr key={horse.horseCode}>
                        <td>{horse.horseCode}</td>
                        <td>{horse.horseName}</td>
                        <td>{horse.foalingYear}</td>
                        <td>{horse.gender}</td>
                        <td>{horse.trainer.trainerCode}</td>
                    </tr>
                ))}
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>  
);
}

export default DataTable;
```

I will also be using filtering on this array with text search inputs

Comment: Why not just use the `data` that you destructure from `useQuery`?

Comment: I want to add filtering etc, so I would need it in a state I presume to set it and render it on the  view?

Comment: @ZackAntonyBucci In that case what you need is to store the filters, not the data itself?

Comment: I am filtering it from a text input, so would I still be able to get the text input at the time to filter on? The text can/will change (see the txtSearch input)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's `onCompleted` not `OnCompleted` - that's why your state stays the same even when `data` is updated with results.

Table should update itself as soon as React commits changes scheduled by `setHorses` call (for sake of simplicity we can see as soon as `setHorses` is called).

For filtering purposes (mentioned in the comments) it's not really required to stare data in local state. You can filter results out using `filter` before mapping them to React components or use `useMemo` hook to prevent unnecessary iterations.

Comment: Silly me.... I also used the useEffect() to set it,:

    useEffect(() => {
        if(data && data.horses) {
            setHorses(data.horses);
        }
    }, [data]);


and its also worked. Thanks.